# splitting a pdf document using ImageMagick

Tags: pdf, vb6, imagemagick

I'm working on a legacy vb6 application and I'm looking to see if anyone has used ImageMagick (or at this point) or any other software to split PDFs using vb6, within the application. I know there are many PDfViewers, that have the functionality to split pdfs, however, I would like to let the user decides on which page they would like to do that.

-i want to display the PDF in WebBrowser compoenent inside the vb6 app

-Let user decide by specifying the pages/page-range for the split

-save all files without user intervention

Comment: Are you trying to save each page of the PDF as a new PDF or some raster format. ImageMagick lets you choose which pages you want to save from the PDF using image.pdf[0,3,4] syntax for pages 1,4,5. However, ImageMagick is not a vector processor and will rasterize your PDF pages. So it would be fine to convert the output to PNG or JPG, but not PDF. Any output PDF would become a raster image imbedded in a vector PDF shell

Comment: @fmw42 - yes, upon splitting, i would want to automatically save each PDF in a folder with faxName_1, faxName_2, etc. Can you recommend another library, or sample code that would help me achieve this? Basically we have files with 10-20 pages, that sometimes need to be split into 3 files, ex: 1-11 is one file, 12-22 2nd file, 23-30 third file

Comment: @Koosh: nothing against ImageMagick, but as You asked for an alternative recommendation which is best suited for searchable PDF's, the great [qvPDF](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qvpdf/files/qvpdf%20v3/qvPDF%20v3.1/) is pure VB6. Just look at the source code.

Comment: @Koosh: did you read my comment? qvPDF is VB6, Just follow the link, download the files and open the project in the VB6 IDE. You will find VB6 Forms and VB6 Modules with readable (!) VB6 code.

Comment: I think you'll get more info from people on SO if you can narrow and clarify the question quite a bit. Its not totally clear what you are really asking. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DaveInCaz - added some more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Koosh`. ImageMagick 6 can do that if you want. But the results will be rasterized versions. Can you post an example multipage PDF and tell me which pages need to be combined? Also what output format? If PDF, they will be rasterized. So perhaps tiff also would be suitable. You seem to have fax documents for which tiff is a good choice.

The basic syntax could be (windows command line syntax):

```
convert -density 300 path/to/image.pdf ( -clone 0-10 +write newpath/to/faxName_1.pdf ) ( -clone 11-21 +write newpath/to/faxName_2.pdf ) ( -clone 22-29 +write newpath/to/faxName_3.pdf ) null:
```

Where -density 300 will increase the quality, but make larger output sizes. Alternately, do

```
convert -density 288 path/to/image.pdf -resize 25% ( -clone 0-10 +write newpath/to/faxName_1.pdf ) ( -clone 11-21 +write newpath/to/faxName_2.pdf ) ( -clone 22-29 +write newpath/to/faxName_3.pdf ) null:
```

That will increase the quality and size of the rasterized PDF by 4x (72*4=288), then resize by 1/4. That should give better quality in the output PDFs.

Note: page numbers in ImageMagick start at 0, not 1.

You could also save to tiff and add -compress FAX or -compress Group4 just before each +write ...

If you are using ImageMagick 7, change convert to magick.

Comment: I want to stay away from the .Tif files and completely make the switch to PDF.

Comment: That is fine, but ImageMagick will rasterize your output PDF files. You can try the above and see if that works. If the output file sizes are too big, then try adding the -compress fax or group4 as described above. If that is not adequate then, you will need to look for other software. I  do not know of any other that would keep the vector format for the output other than using Adobe products, but there could be other for which I am not aware. If you post an example, I could try to process it with my command above.

Comment: I ran the snippet you posted in your answer and it did in fact create the number of documents I told it to. However, the rasterized output is quite choppy and ineligible (since it's a faxed document with manual handwriting).

Comment: You can increase the quality, if you add -density XXX before reading the PDF. See my edit above.